# Is it possible to get a field of a JSON object that is a field of a JSON object without casting twice?

Tags: postgresql

Is the second way the only way to get the second result or is something else possible?

1.

```
select '{"a": [{"b":1}]}'::jsonb -> 'a' ->> 0;
---
{"b": 1}
```

2.

```
select ('{"a": [{"b":1}]}'::jsonb -> 'a' ->> 0)::jsonb -> 'b';
---
1
```

3.

```
select '{"a": [{"b":1}]}'::jsonb -> 'a' ->> 0 -> 'b';
---
No operator matches the given name and argument types...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

casting (back to json) is *probably* only needed in `2` since you're casting the first element of `a` to text via `->>`. try this instead:

```
select '{"a": [{"b":1}]}'::jsonb -> 'a' -> 0 -> 'b';
```

It should work and return 1 (as a json object) which you then might have to cast to int or another appropriate type to reuse in any computation.

alternatively, this should also work, and is shorter as well:

```
select '{"a": [{"b":1}]}'::jsonb #> '{a,0,b}';
```

(disclosure: i'm not at a computer with postgresql. i did not test the above queries)